# Taking data from one worksheet and input it into another based on if two cells have the same value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have this macro check the team name in a worksheet titled "Model", and then check in a worksheet titled "OffensiveStatsPerGame" and if these two have the same name it inputs a value into the worksheet titled "Model" that is one column over from the team name column where it first checked. The value I want it to input is on the "OffensiveStatsPerGame" worksheet 6 columns over from where it checked to see if the team names matched.

```
Sub findThreePointAttempted()

Dim x As Integer, z As Integer, i As Variant, j As Integer, ThreePointAttempts As Integer, toadd As Boolean

Worksheets("OffensiveStatsPerGame").Activate
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1").EntireColumn)

Worksheets("Model").Activate
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1").EntireColumn)


For i = 1 To b
    For j = 1 To x
        If Model.Cells(i, 0) = OffensiveStatsPerGame.Cells(j, 1) Then
            toadd = True
                If toadd = True Then
                    Worksheets("OffensiveStatsPerGame").Activate
                    ThreePointAttempts = OffensiveStatsPerGame.Cells(j, 1).Offset(0, 6)
                    Worksheets("Model").Activate
                    Model.Cells(i, 1) = ThreePointAttempts
                Else
                End If
        Else
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

The code above is giving me a

> Run Time error 424 : Object required

Comment: Where is the error happening?

Comment: Do you have option explicit declared? You haven't defined b as integer.

Comment: Is the worksheet NAME model or the worksheet ID Model? It makes a difference, and you're handling the two different sheets in different ways. If the sheet name as displayed to the user is "Model" then you need to use the same syntax as your other Worksheets("OffensiveStatsPerGame").Activate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't setting "Model" to anything.  Since you are activating your "Model" sheet then you don't need to call that object.

Also, `Cells(i, 0)` doesn't exist since the lowest number a column can be is 1.  You need to change that number to the column number that you want to compare values to.

```
Sub findThreePointAttempted()

Dim x As Integer, i As Integer, b as Integer, j As Integer, ThreePointAttempts As Integer

Worksheets("OffensiveStatsPerGame").Activate
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1").EntireColumn)

Worksheets("Model").Activate
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1").EntireColumn)

For i = 1 To b
    For j = 1 To x
        ThreePointAttempts = Worksheets("OffensiveStatsPerGame").Cells(j, 1)
        If Cells(i, [change this value]) = ThreePointAttempts Then
             Cells(i, 1) = ThreePointAttempts
        Else
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to help, gimme an upvote, fam (and/or mark as answer)